# Does this solution make eval secure?

Tags: javascript, eval

My system needs to let end-users type a function in javascript, but I am worried XSS attack, so I have tried some solutions, like if user type some keywords, avoid save. Currently, I have an idea, but I don't know it is secure enough.

Can you tell me any weakness of this solution?

```js
// end-user definte this port;
var userDefFunString = `function(i){
    // document is undefined
   return document;
}`;

// this template make keyworks become undefined, there are more, but they are to loog, so for demo purpose, I remove them.
var template = `(function secureEval(input){
 var window, document, localStorage, sessionStorage = undefined;
 var fun =` + userDefFunString + `
  
  return fun(input);
})`


let secureFun = eval(template);

//the result should be true
console.log(secureFun("10") === undefined)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review. It might be on-topic for the [code review stack exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: TL;DR: Of course not.

Comment: `var window, document, ...` doesn't make them `undefined`!

Comment: All you need to do is compile V8 with Emscripten.

Comment: @transistor09 Then distribute custom browsers to all users. Probably not a practical solution.

Comment: @DaveNewton Emscripten compiles things to JavaScript. You can then run it on browsers. `TypedArray` is recommended for good performance.

Comment: @transistor09 Ah, gotcha. You're suggesting dropping V8 into the browser? Yikes. Seems easier to sanitize the JS, on the client or not, but OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not! I could use `; alert('Hacked')` or something like:

```
(/* Malicious Code */, _ => console.log('Valid Input Function'))
```

As the input and it would already be a successful XSS. You should never accept JS as input!

You should consider creating a parser token design where you provide them a preset list of functions they can use, then parse them to code.

Just for reference, malicious actors can use a slew of resources to make their attack vectors impossible to detect. Like: [JsFuck](http://www.jsfuck.com/), [Js Obfuscator](http://www.danstools.com/javascript-obfuscate/)

Comment: I think `;alert("can be avoid")` can be avoided. 
var userDefFunString = `function(){   
}; alert("test")`;
 
var template = `(function (input){
 var alert = undefined;
 var fun =` + userDefFunString + `
  
  return fun(input);
})`

Comment: Sure `alert()` was just for example. In reality they may trigger a *CORS* enabled ajax request to submit all form data/download viral payloads on the current page to/from a malicious server, or socket broadcast all the click/keyboard events on the page.

Comment: thanks AP, we will think use no javascript solution.

Comment: If you really have to, try to use a JavaScript Sandboxing solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, AP, JavaScript Sandboxing looks a promising solution.